# Angular validation of dependent text field in an ngRepeat tag

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I have the following ngRepeat code:

```
<div ng-repeat="drug in drugs | orderBy:'drugName'">
    <input id="{{drug.drugName}}"
        class="drugCheckbox" 
        name="{{drug.drugName}}"
        type="checkbox" value="{{drug.drugName}}"
        ng-model="foobar"
        validate-foo
        />
    {{drug.drugName}}
    <!-- this is the error message, one per each repeat element -->
    <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.{{drug.drugName}}.$error.summary">
        Fill in the summary
    </span>

    <input type="text"
        name="summary-{{drug.drugName}}"
        id="summary-{{drug.drugName}}"
        placeholder="Summary"/>

</div>
```

My validateFoo directive:

```
app.directive('validateFoo', function(){
  return{
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {

        ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
            var id= attr.id;
            //if the checkbox is checked, see if the text field has been filled in
            if(viewValue) {
                var val= document.getElementById('summary-' + id).value;
                if(val.length == 0) {
                    ctrl.$setValidity("summary", false);
                    return undefined;
                }
                else {
                    ctrl.$setValidity(id, true);
                    return viewValue;
                }
            }

        });
    }
  }
});
```

I cannot get the validation to work for any of the checkboxes, I am not clear on what to use for "ng-show" in the error message span element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First of all that's because all fields will be registered in your formController under name `{{drug.drugName}}`.
2. Second thing is that there is no `myForm.{{drug.drugName}}.$invalid` in scope. You probably tried to do `myForm[drug.drugName].$invalid`. But it will not work anyway - look at *1.*
3. I think that there still is no proper way to set `name` field dynamically in `ng-repeat`. Instead you need to create tour own directive, that will build repeated list elements as String, then append it to your HTML and $compile it place.

**EDIT**

I have developed one solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/ulfryk/gejfeLp7/

**EDIT 2:**

I've developed even simpler solution ( http://jsfiddle.net/ulfryk/5wq7539r/ ):

```
app.directive('fixRepeatedModelName', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            if (!attrs.name) return;
            ngModelCtrl.$name = attrs.name;
        },
        priority: '-100',
        require: 'ngModel'
    };
});
```

And add `fix-repeated-model-name` attribute to any `ng-model` with dynamic (`{{ }}` dependent) `name` placed inside `ng-repeat`. And it now works :)

Comment: Regarding "3": myForm.{{drug.drugName}} is working, i have unique names for the elements. The way I am doing ng-repeat seems to work fine, so I want to stay on that trail and see if anyone else has an idea

Comment: I did check and `myForm.{{drug.drugName}}` didn't work. As `name="{{drug.drugName}}`"` did not append any inputController to formController :/

Comment: I only checked by seeing what was rendered in the HTML source, and I get, for example: name="advil". Is it not too difficult to explain how you knew 'did not append any inputController to formController'?

Comment: I made a change in the span error message to: "myForm.{{drug.drugName}}.$error.summary"; then I changed the directive to ctrl.$setValidity("summary", false);....it is still not working, but maybe it is closer?

Comment: I ran a test that hard coded two elements, and it worked. So, I think you are right, that I need to make a directive to build the elements. Any link get me going on it? I've looked at some online help, but I thought if you had a specific site or article...

Comment: I just own my knowledge. Make directive that watches collection on scope, and on digest it builds html as string dependant on collection and then appends it into parent and $compiles in place...

Comment: Ok, I made jsfiddle with `ulf:repeated-input-group` directive that adds interpolation layer before `ng-repeat` contents get compiled so it interpolates anything that is inside `{%` .. `%}`.     DEMO:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ulfryk/gejfeLp7/) 

   So you got there angular validated dynamic form :)